# Find one or multiple of the best players on a team with the highest scores across multiple quiz's

Tags: excel, vba

For the following image:
[image]

I have the list of unique players in our quiz nights. I need a way to select and show the best player across all games we play.
Each game is on its own separate table. We have only had 2 quiz nights so far but would like to do more so it needs to be dynamic.

I need a function to select the best player on any of the teams (they can play on different teams each game) who plays in the highest-scoring team.
So a function that selects all the headers, and compares against the unique list of players, and then finds the player who has played on both/all the highest scoring/winning teams for all games that we have played, and will play.
And needs to be able to add a new table to index each time a new game is played.

Also, each time we play, there can be more or less teams playing.

Edit: Thanks @CDP1802 for the excellent answer. It worked perfectly.
I added some nice formatting and colouring, and etc to the final table. For anyone trying to achieve a similar result, here is the final code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Call FindHighestPlayer
End Sub

Function FindHighestPlayer()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, tbl As ListObject
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, data As Range
    Dim team As String, score As Single, qcount As Long
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") ' score sheet
    
    Dim dict As Object, key, ar
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' scan each table
    For Each tbl In ws.ListObjects
        Set data = tbl.DataBodyRange
        For c = 1 To tbl.HeaderRowRange.Columns.Count
            ' don't count answer and question
            If InStr(1, LCase(tbl.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, c)), "question") = 0 And InStr(1, LCase(tbl.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, c)), "answer") = 0 Then
                ' team from header row
                team = tbl.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, c)
                qcount = tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
                score = WorksheetFunction.Sum(data.Cells(1, c).Resize(qcount))
                
                ' update team members performance
                For Each key In Split(team, ", ")
                    key = Trim(key) ' team members name
                    
                    If dict.exists(key) Then
                        ar = dict(key)
                        ar(0) = ar(0) + score
                        ar(1) = ar(1) + qcount
                        ar(2) = ar(2) + 1 ' number of quizes
                        dict(key) = ar
                    Else
                        dict.Add key, Array(score, qcount, 1)
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    Next
    
    ' dump  results to another sheet
    Set ws = Sheet2 ' wb.sheets("Player Scores")
    With ws
        .Cells.Clear
        .Range("A1:D1") = Array("Player", "Score", "Avg %", "Number of Quiz's Played")
        .Range("C:C").NumberFormat = "0%"
        r = 1
        For Each key In dict
            r = r + 1
            ar = dict(key)
            .Cells(r, 1) = key
            .Cells(r, 2) = ar(0) & " out of " & ar(1)
            .Cells(r, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=" & ar(0) & "/" & ar(1)
            .Cells(r, 4) = ar(2)
        Next
    End With
    
    ' Sort table
    With ws.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add ws.Range("C1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
            Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange ws.Range("A1:D" & r)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    
    ' Format headers
    With ws
        .Range("A1:D1").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Range("A1:D1").VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .Range("A1:D1").Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Range("A1:D1").Font.Size = 15
        .Range("A1:D1").Font.Color = RGB(68, 84, 106)
        .Range("A1:D1").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Range("A1:D1").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick
        .Range("A1:D1").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Color = RGB(68, 114, 196)
    End With
    
    ' Delete existing format conditions
    ws.Range("A1:D" & r).FormatConditions.Delete
    ' Format data
    With ws
        .Range("A1:D" & r).Locked = True
        .Range("B2:B" & r).NumberFormat = "General"
        .Range("B2:B" & r).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        .Range("D2:D" & r).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    
    ' Format Avg
    Dim cs As ColorScale
    Set cs = Range("C2:C" & r).FormatConditions.AddColorScale(ColorScaleType:=3)
    With cs
        ' the first color is light red
        With .ColorScaleCriteria(1)
            .FormatColor.Color = RGB(248, 105, 107)
            .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
            .Value = 0
        End With
        ' the second color is light yellow
        With .ColorScaleCriteria(2)
            .FormatColor.Color = RGB(255, 235, 132)
            .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
            .Value = 0.5
        End With
        ' the third color is light green
        With .ColorScaleCriteria(3)
            .FormatColor.Color = RGB(99, 190, 123)
            .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
            .Value = 1
        End With
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: you don't have a value for each player, how can you find the best player when the points are given to the whole team?!

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code attempt then explain what's not working with your code. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: I think a similar question was asked on here for Golf or even Football, perhaps look for top 5 or top 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another sheet to collate the results and sort to find the best.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub LeagueTable()

   Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, tbl As ListObject
   Dim r As Long, c As Long, data As Range
   Dim team As String, score As Single, qcount As Long

   Set wb = ThisWorkbook
   Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") ' score sheet

   Dim dict As Object, key, ar
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

   ' scan each table
   For Each tbl In ws.ListObjects
       Set data = tbl.DataBodyRange
       For c = 1 To tbl.HeaderRowRange.Columns.Count
           ' team from header row
           team = tbl.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, c)
           qcount = tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
           score = WorksheetFunction.Sum(data.Cells(1, c).Resize(qcount))

           ' update team members performance
           For Each key In Split(team, ",")
               key = Trim(key) ' team members name
               
               If dict.exists(key) Then
                    ar = dict(key)
                    ar(0) = ar(0) + score
                    ar(1) = ar(1) + qcount
                    ar(2) = ar(2) + 1 ' number of quizes
                    dict(key) = ar
               Else
                    dict.Add key, Array(score, qcount, 1)
               End If
           Next
       Next
    Next

   ' dump results to another sheet
    Set ws = Sheet2 'wb.sheets("Player Scores")
    With ws
        .Cells.Clear
        .Range("A1:E1") = Array("Player", "Score", "Count", "Avg %", "Quiz Count")
        .Range("D:D").NumberFormat = "0%"
        r = 1
        For Each key In dict
            r = r + 1
            ar = dict(key)
            .Cells(r, 1) = key
            .Cells(r, 2) = ar(0)
            .Cells(r, 3) = ar(1)
            .Cells(r, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]/RC[-1]"
            .Cells(r, 5) = ar(2)
        Next
    End With
    ' sort table
    With ws.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add ws.Range("D1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange ws.Range("A1:E" & r)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    ws.Activate
    ws.Range("A1").Select
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked absolutely brilliantly. Thanks so much. This is even better than what I wanted. I added a small If check before getting team name, qcount, and score to not count the Answer and Question columns in any table.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand your question you need to detect which column name has the largest value in the last row
so first you need a new row you may hide contain the sum of ones above without "/16"
and in the cell use (index & match & max)

```
=INDEX("range of players"; MATCH( MAX("range of scores"); "range of scores" ; 0))
```

you could use "," instead of ";" according to your office numbers and date settings